# where should i add specify extension for mime types in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

```
$photo = Input::file('photo');

if($photo) {
    $size = $photo->getSize();
    $mime = $photo->getMimeType();
    $orignalname = $photo->getClientOriginalName();
    $orignalextension = $photo->getClientOriginalExtension();

    $destination = "Documents/edifile/";
    $filename = time().str_replace(' ', '_', $orignalname);
    $photo->move($destination,$filename);
```

where i have add this line **'file' => 'required|max:10000|mimes:edi,jpeg'** i want to upload this extension file only.?

Answer (score 1):

You should add this in your form validation. See [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation) form Validation for how to use. 
And here is a code sample.

//Assume photo is your controller method

```
public function photo(Request $request) { 
   $this->validate($request, [

      'photo' => 'required|max:10000|mimes:edi,jpeg', //add your validation

]);
```

}

Comment: for jpeg its works good, i tried for edi file but it's only redirecting file not uploaded.. anything i want to change more in controller?

Comment: Check `edi` file mime type by print `echo $photo->getMimeType();`. Before that remove `edi` from validation otherwise it will redirect again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add validation logic inside your controller.
Check the official documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic), it is very simple.